# Boot loop after messing with the smallest width option in developer options. (Redmi 5 plus)

Tags: adb, boot-loop, bootloader, miui

so I was bored and I decided to check some developer options to see what they can do...
I found this option called 'smallest width', at first I set it from 392 to 100 and it automatically set itself to two hundred something I believe. So I did the same thing but this time I set it to 1000 thinking that it would automatically set itself to the max value possible... But it didn't. Right after pressing 'Ok', my screen became soo small and a message pooped up saying "System is not responding", then my phone restarted to recovery. Unlike many people who were facing this problem on the internet, My phone's bootloader is unlocked, I have TWRP recovery installed, my phone is rooted and I had USB debugging on. I rebooted to bootloader and tried "adb devices" but my phone wasn't there. After that, I booted to TWRP and clicked Mount then checked all boxes (I couldn't check storage) and clicked Mount USB Storage. This time my phone showed up in the list. Check the image below.

I don't know if it's okay that it's saying recovery instead of device, but I ran "adb shell wm density reset", it didn't work and same with "adb shell wm size reset".

As you can see in the image below, there was no error but the phone still didn't want to boot. After that I tried to check my current screen size and density using "adb shell wm size" and "adb shell wm density", but there was no response.

I also checked the build.prop file in /system and found this line "persist.miui.density_v2=440", I changed it to 220, nothing happened.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zalow.png

Now my question is, why is there no response when I run "adb shell wm size/density"? It doesn't work in the TWRP terminal as well. Is this command supposed to be in the /sbin directory? Because I couldn't find it there. How can I add it if it is not there? And lastly, if you can suggest any other way to fix my phone that would help me a lot. Thank you so much.

Comment: When booted into TWRP, find your relevant density property in /data/property/persistent_properties and change it there. Use VIM or nano to edit that file. Do not pull it into PC and than push it back.

Answer (score 1):

Wipe all data and restart. That's what I did after I made the same mistake of changing the width drastically from 392 to 1000.

It messes with the UI and goes into a loop.

Answer (score 1):

adb reset  commands worked for me.

I had USB debugging on. And  a few seconds after reboot(after MIUI animation) my device showed in `adb devices`. Then I used `adb shell wm density reset`